# this. undefined inside dropzone success callback vuejs2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone.js with Vuejs2. The file upload is working fine however, inside the `success` callback function i cannot assign the response to an object of the parent.

Here is a sample of my implementation:

```
<script>
    import vueDropzone from "vue2-dropzone";

      export default {
        components: {
          vueDropzone
        },
        props: {
        },
        data: () => ({
            data: {
              name: ''
            },
            dropOptions: {
                url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
                maxFileSize: 10,
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                success: (file, response) => {
                if (response.message == "success"){
                  this.data.name = response.name;                
                  this.add();
                }
                else{
                  console.log('Error Uploading file');
                }
           }
       }),
     };
</script>
```

the error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

I tried the solutions found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558252/javascript-vuejs-variable-access/42558599) but its still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/docs/dist/#/events), you're using it wrong.

`dropOptions` should only contain it's [configuration](https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/docs/dist/#/props), not the events.

You need to use the vue-2-dropzones [events](https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/docs/dist/#/events), in your case `vdropzone-success(file, response)`, so:

```
<vue-dropzone
  ref="myVueDropzone"
  id="dropzone"
  :options="dropOptions"
  v-on:vdropzone-success="someSuccessMethod">
</vue-dropzone>

...
data() { /* ... */ },
methods: {
  someSuccessMethod(file, response) {
    // your logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply does not work because `this` is binded to another object than you think. It is some default error from people switching or learning JavaScript.

`dropOptions` is an object. `this` in the `success` functions refers to the `dropOptions` object and not to the parent object of it.

So `dropOptions` has no field `data` hence is `undefined` and you can not access `name`.

See: [access parent object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789892/access-parent-object-in-javascript)

EDIT: For further investigation, please provide some code of what you have done with the link you posted. This seems to go to the right direction but from a simple "does not work", we can not tell you what else you need to keep in mind.